# why does my templates won't refresh in my ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

i m new to ionic..
i made a templates and use it like
`$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/answercard.html'....`

And the problem is i can't update this html. It's like i changed something in this html. But nothing changed when i refresh the page.(i tested my app in browser)It's exactly like the yesterday's html file i saved.

i tried `<ion-view cache-view="false">`, but it didn't work.(seems in the newest version of ionic, this is droped.) And i tried `$stateProvider.state('app', {cache:false,})`. And this still the same.

i figure out a way, but it's not the solution. i will have to make a new file and paste exact the old file's content to the new file every time my template won't respond. And the new file can respond to my change..

so..could anyone help.. thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh ? Or saving html ? Something persistant ? Show us some more code.

Comment: for instance, i have a <div> xxxxxx </div>, and the page with show this div and everything in there. but if i delete this div. nothing gonna be delete on the page. the page shows exact the same like the div exists. i m guessing it's a cache issue.